# PowerCLI Get VMs those fit some conditions

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I'm trying to get our some Linux distros from vCenter by using PowerCLI. But I don't want to get Appliance VMs. So I have 2 different successful PowerCLI scripts those can find these machines. I want merge these scripts but I'm new on PowerCLI and it's syntax.

I'm sharing these scripts at below:

Non-Appliance List:

```
Get-VM | `
Get-Annotation | `
Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Appliance"} | `
Where-Object {$_.value -eq 'No'} | `
Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Documents\non-appliance-list.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

---

Linux List:

```
Get-View -Property @("Name", "Config.GuestFullName","Guest.GuestFullName") | `
Select -Property Name, @{N="COS";E={$_.Config.GuestFullName}}, @{N="ROS";E={$_.Guest.GuestFullName}} | `
Where-Object ({$_.ROS -like 'Centos*' -or $_.ROS -like 'Suse*' -or $_.ROS -like 'Ubuntu*'}) | `    
Select AnnotatedEntity,Name,Value | `
Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Documents\linux-list.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

---

Script I imagined but doesn't worked:

```
Get-VM | `
Get-Annotation | `
Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Appliance"} | `
Where-Object {$_.value -eq 'No'} | `
Get-View -Property @("Name", "Config.GuestFullName","Guest.GuestFullName") | `
Select -Property Name, @{N="COS";E={$_.Config.GuestFullName}}, @{N="ROS";E={$_.Guest.GuestFullName}} | `
Where-Object ({$_.ROS -like 'Centos*' -or $_.ROS -like 'Suse*' -or $_.ROS -like 'Ubuntu*'}) | `    
Select AnnotatedEntity,Name,Value | `
Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Documents\linux--list.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

---

Maybe It has been a XY-Question. If you have a better way to get Linux VMs those are not appliance, you can say me this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off making use of some variables along the way to help make this a bit easier.

Example:

```
$LinuxVMs = Get-VM | `
Get-Annotation | `
Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Appliance"} | `
Where-Object {$_.value -eq 'No'}
```

Now you have the ability to pipeline the LinuxVMs variable into the Export-Csv cmdlet if you need as well as reference it for your second script.

Example:

```
$LinuxVMs | Get-View -Property @("Name", "Config.GuestFullName","Guest.GuestFullName") | `
Select -Property Name, @{N="COS";E={$_.Config.GuestFullName}}, @{N="ROS";E={$_.Guest.GuestFullName}} | `
Where-Object ({$_.ROS -like 'Centos*' -or $_.ROS -like 'Suse*' -or $_.ROS -like 'Ubuntu*'}) | `    
Select AnnotatedEntity,Name,Value | `
Export-Csv C:\Users\me\Documents\linux-list.csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: I changed the script like this before your answer by chance. I'm sure now it's true way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have just mashed the scripts together, piping the first into the second.
This won't work.

You can have each script block in a single script, then merge the resulting csv's using one of the methods here:
[Merging multiple CSV files into one using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892957/merging-multiple-csv-files-into-one-using-powershell)

[Stinkyfriend's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713589/stinkyfriend) code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName | Import-Csv | Export-Csv .\merged\merged.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Comment: Tell me did I understand correct? You say, first of all export a non-appliance list and run second script by using this list and export a new list.