# Import-Csv picks only first column or Export-Csv writes only first column

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv, export-csv

I need to merge CSV files and want to use following command from post
[Merging multiple CSV files into one using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892957/merging-multiple-csv-files-into-one-using-powershell).

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.csv | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Import-Csv |
    Export-Csv .\merged\merged.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

However, only the first column of the source CSV files ends up in `merged.csv`.

Comment: Please provide sample input as well as the desired and actual output for that sample input. [Edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: I suspect that the first csv file has only one column or that column is the only common column name among all the csv files.

Comment: That code will only work if all the csv files have the **same headers** in the **same order**, if it's not working one of these will be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue ...

The tool generating the csv files added as top line
sep=,

With this Excel openes the csv already correctly formatted.

After removing this line from the csv files all is working as expected with the Import-csv and Export-csv command.

Best regards,
Axel