# Merge multiple csv files, ignoring metadata line and handling different quotings

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to merge CSV files in Powershell. I've read numerous answers here but I'm stuck on this problem.

I have a list of csv files, 2 difficulties :

- [A] each file has a metadataline, the headers are in the second line.
- [B] each file has the same structure, but sometimes quotes surround the column to escape the content.

Thanks to this question : [Merging multiple CSV files into one using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892957/merging-multiple-csv-files-into-one-using-powershell),
I'm able to solve these two problems individually.

However, I'm stuck at combining the solutions.

**Partial solution A**

*Skips every metadata line as well as header for subsequent files*

Adapting the answer from [kemiller2002](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1942/kemiller2002):

```
$sourcefilefolderPath = "C:\CSV_folder"
$destinationfilePath = "C:\appended_files.csv"

$getHeader = $true
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcefilefolderPath -Filter *.csv -Recurse| foreach {
    $filePath = $_.FullName

    $lines = $lines = Get-Content $filePath
        $linesToWrite = switch($getHeader) {
           $true  {$lines | Select -Skip 1}  # skips only the metadata line
           $false {$lines | Select -Skip 2}  # skips both the metadata line as well as headers
        }
    $getHeader = False
    Add-Content $destination_file $linesToWrite
}
```

The problem : `Import-Csv $destination_file` give inconsistent results, as the quoting can be different for each source file.

**Partial solution B**

*handles successfully random quoted columns*

Solution provided by [stinkyfriend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713589/stinkyfriend).

`Import-Csv` seems to import the data gracefully when the column quoting, however different from one column to the other, is consistent for each line of the source file.

I could not combine this solution with the one above.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcefilefolderPath -File  -Filter *.csv -Recurse |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
  Import-Csv |
  Export-Csv $destination_file -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

**Solution C**

*produces blank file on my PC*

using suggestion from [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcefilefolderPath -File  -Filter *.csv -Recurse | foreach {
    Write-Host $_.FullName |
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv |
    Export-Csv $destinationfilePath -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

--- EDIT ---

**RESULT**

I could solve the problem by creating appended_files.csv using the first matching source file and then append to it.

```
$pattern_sourceFile = "*.csv*"

$list_files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcefilefolderPath -File -Recurse | Where { 
   $_FullName -match $pattern_sourcefile }

Get-Content $list_files[0].FullName | 
 Select-Object -Skip 1 | # skips metadataline
 ConvertFrom-Csv | Export-Csv $destinationfilePath -NoTypeInformation

$list_files | 
 Select-Object -Skip 1 | # skips $array_files[0]
 foreach { Get-Content $_.FullName | 
           Select-Object -Skip 1 | # skips metadata line
           ConvertFrom-Csv |
           Export-Csv $destinationfilePath -NoTypeInformation -Append }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead of `Import-Csv`, this way you can still control how many lines to skip:

```bsh
Get-Content $file |Select -Skip 1 |ConvertFrom-Csv
```

So you'll end up with something like:

```bsh
$sourcefilefolderPath = "C:\CSV_folder"
$destinationfilePath = "C:\appended_files.csv"

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcefilefolderPath -Filter *.csv -Recurse | foreach {
    Get-Content $_.FullName |Select-Object -Skip 1 |ConvertFrom-Csv |Export-Csv -Path $destinationfilePath -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```