# powershell active directory excel report

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have those two scripts

```
$Path = 'C:\Users\akouyoumjian\Desktop\Report4.csv'
Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp | 

Select-Object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss')}} | Export-Csv -Path $Path –notypeinformation
```

and this one:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "windows 7") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} -Properties OperatingSystem | Sort Name | select -Unique OperatingSystem
```

I would like to merge those into one file
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Why do you think `os version` is an AD user attribute?

Comment: example: Name(name of user) Stamp(time of last log) OperationSystem(Windows 7)

Comment: or if there is a way to add operation system to the second command

Comment: Please update your question with a few sample lines of data of what you are expecting your output to look like. Please be very specific.

Answer (score 0):

would this answer found here work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27893253/10542366

This will append all the files together reading them one at a time:

```
get-childItem "YOUR_DIRECTORY\*.txt" 
| foreach {[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText
 ("YOUR_DESTINATION_FILE", [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName))}
```

This one will place a new line at the end of each file entry if you need it:

```
get-childItem "YOUR_DIRECTORY\*.txt" | foreach
{[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText("YOUR_DESTINATION_FILE", 
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName) + [System.Environment]::NewLine)}
```

Skipping the first line:

```
$getFirstLine = $true

get-childItem "YOUR_DIRECTORY\*.txt" | foreach {
    $filePath = $_

    $lines =  $lines = Get-Content $filePath  
    $linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
           $true  {$lines}
           $false {$lines | Select -Skip 1}

    }

    $getFirstLine = $false
    Add-Content "YOUR_DESTINATION_FILE" $linesToWrite
    }
```