# Export RBAC from all subscriptions in Azure AD to one csv

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I have dozen of subscriptions and its very difficult to output all role assignments from all resources from all subscriptions at once. I'm currently using the one below but the output is looped for each subscription per csv file. How do I get output into one sheet preferably?

```
Get-AzSubscription | foreach-object {

    Write-Verbose -Message "Changing to Subscription $($_.Name)" -Verbose

    Set-AzContext -TenantId $_.TenantId -SubscriptionId $_.Id -Force
    $Name     = $_.Name
    $TenantId = $_.TenantId
    $SubId    = $_.SubscriptionId  

    Get-AzRoleAssignment -IncludeClassicAdministrators | Select-Object RoleDefinitionName,DisplayName,SignInName,ObjectType,Scope,
    @{name="TenantId";expression = {$TenantId}},@{name="SubscriptionName";expression = {$Name}},@{name="SubscriptionId";expression = {$SubId}} -OutVariable ra

    # Also export the individual subscriptions to excel documents on your Desktop.
    # One file per subscription
    $ra | Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\Export-AzRoleAssignment\$Name.csv -NoTypeInformation

}
```

Comment: What would be a best way to add export AAD groups and resolve their members?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-Append` parameter for the `Export-Csv` command.

So, your last line would look something like this:

`$ra | Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\Export-AzRoleAssignment\csv_with_everything.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append`

Or you could merge all the csv files into big file after it has run e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43972739/1713589