# Recursively merge identically-named .CSV files into a single file

Tags: csv, merge

Been trying variations of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27892957/merging-multiple-csv-files-into-one-using-powershell) and [this](https://www.tomnash.eu/how-to-combine-multiple-csv-files-into-one-using-cmd/), but I think what's tripping things up is the fact that they're all named the same and all the examples I've seen specify wildcards (*.csv) for `copy` or `Get-ChildItem | Import-Csv`.

Sources:

`C:\foo\bar\list.csv`

`c:\foo\foobar\list.csv`

`c:\foo\foobarfoo\list.csv`

`...`

Destination:
`c:\foo\merged.csv`

Help a tired old brother out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$getFirstLine = $true

get-childItem "c:\path\to\files\*.csv" | foreach {
$filePath = $_

$lines = Get-Content $filePath  
$linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
       $true  {$lines}
       $false {$lines | Select -Skip 1}

}

$getFirstLine = $false
Add-Content "c:\path\to\files\final.csv" $linesToWrite
}
```

https://code.adonline.id.au/merge-multiple-csvs-with-powershell/